# dashDB Launch Server Error

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have added a dashDB to my app and restaged as required.  Unfortunately, when I select the Launch button I get a Server Error 500 page.  In the Details I get the following:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&state=c0241f7f-cf7a-4463-9c29-502c5b4f5efb&scope=openid&client_id=mccpserviceadmin&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmccp.ng.bluemix.net%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2Fbmmccp.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.N1XmBAm3ZJQExj1FD18JFLPFkECuizGJJVrT0dTrUeZPeH2gIj6nqk6tGlChoSWMHrxdhnH59d0272OkBiT-AaDasYQsGufXwZkmqSJ72fxbwLBefKgu_fgi1rxylhNM0rs5k-YNDk6SW69vwNWI-Np3ywGW8wTRHx26tXQ8_lFzeGP6K0Mke-cQT-u-HXU6c28E6R9XHGuiahRyKHV6eY_Ohvp5I_UE2E3JOUoXVpnj-F34JsmeW6mnUalmJDVJrzVfUJ0MVb9Kyej0eZDnQOV2cnm_auoTR2U_JoIoaZb6ESfoN6nt_Z7ALPZ0txXsVGyHzWf95enwVAPstfLCpw. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Which I can't decipher.
I read in this forum where one can login using the details from the VCAP_VARIABLES which I was able to do successfully.  Interestingly I have annother app on bluemix that also has a dashdb that was accessible but now isn't.
I have dropped the dashDB a couple of times and also created it but left it unbound all for no joy.
Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Must have been something on the bluemix side.  Just checked it now and it is fine.

Comment: The DashDB service is undergoing scheduled maintenance today. It will be down for an hour starting at these times in the different regions: London 11 pm GMT, Dallas 9 pm US-EST, Sydney2/12 2 am AEDT. For status updates on the services, go to https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bluemix problem as the dashdb is working fine from the Launch button and I can see the data I loaded when I logged in via the vcap variables.